# Add whitespace after every word in file (Java)

Tags: java, file, whitespace

I want to add a space after every word in a file
E.G thisisatest becomes this is a test

I was able to make it add a space at the end of the file using .write

This is the code I used to add spaces

```
try {
    String filename = "test.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
    fw.write(" ");
    fw.close();
} catch(IOException ioe)
  {
      System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
  }
```

This is the code I used to find the words

```
 try {
     File file = new File(WORD_FILE);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = scanner.nextLine();
         for(String word : line.split("\\s")) {
            if (!word.isEmpty())
                System.out.println(word);
          }
      }
      scanner.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
   }
```

It added a blank space at the end of the file but what I wanted it to do was add a space after every word

Comment: You need to read the entire file and the write it back to the filesystem.

Comment: Well, that would require some reading first right?

Comment: Break your problem down. First identify the words, then add the space.

Comment: Divide your problem in small task to understand what you do. First you need to read the file. Then you have to independantly solve the problem "how to identify a word in a String". Then adapt the solution of this problem to your main problem. Then add the white space after each inditified word. Finally write back to the file

Comment: I have already code that reads the file and outputs the words just need to add a space after each word

Comment: You will not be able to do that unless you specifiy a pattern that matches what ou define as  a 'word'. Please show us your code

Comment: Well, if you have a code that does that, you should share that code in your question - not the code that appends a space to the file, as that is not related to your problem. Please [edit] your question and show your current code.

Comment: hint : In the code you shown, you call the line that "add a whitespace" only once. Maybe if you call it multiple times it's better ?

Comment: Not a trivial problem: how do you determine word boundaries? Eg. "basketball" or "basket" "ball", "insanity" or "in" "sanity"; Properly parsing words from a mashed together string could be quite difficult..

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Nomen est omen, isn't it?

Comment: This is confusing. You read the words from the original file by splitting them on space. This means they already have spaces between them.

Comment: The reason I want to add the space is to work out the row and column as without it the space recognises each word as a new line and in the file no words have a space after them so I wanted to add a space after each word as when I did this manually it worked out the correct row and column

Comment: This is the test before adding the spaces                                             thisisatest: line 1, position 0                                                                             This is the test when I add the spaces in manually                                          this: line 1, position 0
is: line 1, position 5
a: line 1, position 8
test: line 1, position 10 (the second output is the output I want)

Comment: This is a non-trivial exercise. For example, how would you parse "thesearedear?" Would it be "these are dear" or "the seared ear?" The latter doesn't make sense but all of these are valid words. So some form of AI might be required. Once all the words are properly identified the actual adding of a space is trivial by splitting on the boundaries and inserting a space between the words.

Answer (score 2):

One needs to read and write separately, as one cannot *insert* on an opened file, just append as you did.

```
String filename = "test.txt";
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset(); // StandardCharsets.UTF_8
Path path = Paths.get(filename);
List<String> lines = Files.lines(path, charset)
    .map(line -> line.replaceAll("\\s+", "$0 "))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.write(path, lines, charset);
```

Here I read the lines as a `Stream<String>` of single lines.
I replace whitespace `\\s+` with the same plus an extra space.

However to split "thisisatest" into words you need English knowledge.

```
    .map(line -> replaceWords(line))

List<String> allWords = Arrays.asList(
    "are", "a",
    "island", "is",
    "tests", "test",
    "thistle", "this", "th" /*5th*/
);

String replaceWords(String line) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ... loop through letter sequences (multiple words)
    ... and split them by sorted dictionary.
    return sb.toString();
}
```

As this looks like home work, or at least some interesting effort should remain, the rest is up to you.

Comment: Just for my Personal interest: do you have a perfoamnce oriented approach on your solution? Because solving any problem with your solution requires knowing "all" words and I wonder how to implelent this in Java with regards to performance?

Comment: I would rather immediately look at _natural language processing_ frameworks (for word stemming and so on). But free dictionaries exist, and a tree with a letter would be feasible: `-(a(-,r(e(-)), i(s(-, l(a(n(d))))), ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some anwser that may help you to find an approach to your problem:

The problem you have is that a scanner reads a so called `Token` and for seperating tokens, a scanner uses a `Delimiter`. The default delimiter is the `whitespace`.

So no matter how you will solve your problem, you will need to have a delimiter that is used to separate what you call word. To be precise, I will call it `Token`.

You can use a custom delimiter in a `Scanner` by calling
  `scanner.useDelimiter(",") //e.g. use  a comma`

When you use a BufferedReader, you need to split your read lines by `String.split()` which lets you specifiy a custom delimiter too as a parameter.

Comment: OP wants magic, see end of first line: *E.G **thisisatest** becomes **this is a test***.

Comment: I tried my Best to explain what it needs to Do this exercise. Also the other answer wont work because it requires knowing All words...